# Web App Access iOS "Square" Camera

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-applications

So I'm accessing the Camera App via a web app with the following code.

`<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">`

Easy peasy, right? What I'd like to know is if there's a way to launch the Camera App in "Square" mode?